# finding axis rotation angles to go from one direction vector to another in directX/c++

Tags: c++, math, rotation, directx, game-physics

I am working on building a game in c++ with directX, and I am trying to make my flashlight geometry rotate in the direction of the camera. Getting the light to rotate is easy because I can change the direction vector for the light equations.

I have the current direction vector the flashlight is is pointing, and the new direction vector for the way the camera is pointing. I need to be able to rotate the geometry to this direction.

How can I use the two direction vectors to calculate the amount of rotation around each axis necessary to get my flashlight to the correct orientation?

Thanks,

-Jake

Comment: Hm, couldn't you just break down the vector components to make 3 sets of 2D vectors (aligned to the XY, YZ, and XZ planes), and find the angle for each corresponding axis using dot product?

Comment: That should work, I was trying that, but I think I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Calculate the rotation axis with the cross product of both directions and the angle with `acos` and the dot product.